# Executing yum clean expire-cache and remove commands using ansible script

Tags: ansible, yum

Could anyone please support with equivalent tasks for clean and remove ?

```
yum clean expire-cache
yum -y remove packageX-S
yum -y install packageX-S
```

I got install already...

```yaml
- name: deploy
  yum:
    name: llc-html-clients-S
    state: latest
```

Comment: Take care `latest` is not a real equialent to `yum install`, see explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR;

Here are your equivalent tasks:

```yaml
- name: clean
  command: yum clean expire-cache

- name: remove
  yum:
    name: pkg-to-remove
    state: absent

- name: install
  yum:
    name: pkg-to-install
    state: present
```

---

Installing and removing is done with the same module [`yum`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_module.html).

When installing would test the `installed` or `present` state, removing is about testing `removed` or `absent` state.

Install:

```yaml
- name: install
  yum:
    name: pkg-to-install
    state: present
```

**Take care:** `yum install` and `state: latest` are not the same, when the `yum` command will install if the package is absent and do nothing if it is present already, `state: latest` will do an install if the package is absent but **also** a `yum update pkg-to-install` if the package is not at its latest version.
The real equivalent is `state: present`.

> `present` and `installed` will simply ensure that a desired package is installed.
>   `latest` will update the specified package if it's not of the latest available version.

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_module.html#parameter-state*</sup>

Remove:

```yaml
- name: remove
  yum:
    name: pkg-to-remove
    state: absent
```

Then for the `clean`, sadly, there was a choice to not implement it, as this is not something that can be done in an idempotent way.

See this note on `yum` module page

> - The yum module does not support clearing yum cache in an idempotent way, so it was decided not to implement it, the only method is to use command and call the yum command directly, namely “command: yum clean all”
>     https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/31450#issuecomment-352889579

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_module.html#notes*</sup>

So as pointed in the note, you could actually go by a simple [`command`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html#command-module).

```yaml
- name: clean
  command: yum clean expire-cache
```

So those are equivalent:

- in bash

```sh
yum clean expire-cache
yum -y remove pkg-to-remove
yum -y install pkg-to-install
```

- in playbook

```yaml
- name: clean
  command: yum clean expire-cache

- name: remove
  yum:
    name: pkg-to-remove
    state: absent

- name: install
  yum:
    name: pkg-to-install
    state: present
```

Comment: maybe you could help as well with this thread :) please ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62259666/switch-to-another-ssh-user-with-password-using-ansible-script

Answer (score 0):

Better remove path instead of using yum clean all,
feel free use below task for activity:

```
---
# tasks file for yum cache clean

 - name: Cleaning up yum cache
   file:
    path: /var/cache/yum/
    state: absent
...
```

### if playbook required: use role upper as task

cat clear_yum_cache.yml

```
---
 - name: Playbook for clearing yum cache
   hosts: all
   user: <<adduserhere>>
   become: yes
   become_method: sudo
   become_user: root
   gather_facts: True
   pre_tasks:
    - debug: msg="Beginning clean yum"
   roles:
    - patch-yum-clean
   post_tasks:
    - debug: msg="Yum cache clean completed successfully"
...
```

Enjoy,